# Which directories dpkg removes?

Tags: files, dpkg

While browsing the filesystem, I have encountered a file named `.placeholder` in `/etc/cron.d/`. In the file, the following was written:

```
#DO NOT EDIT OR REMOVE
#This file is a simple placeholder to keep dpkg from removing this directory
```

So I wonder, does `dpkg` removes directories at its will? Or more precisely; what types of directories does `dpkg` remove?

Comment: `dpkg` is a program that runs on command. It doesn't just go around deleting things whenever it wants to. I assume this just a cache folder or something that specifies it shouldn't be removed if someone runs a remove on its associated program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dpkg` removes empty directories, cleaning up after packages that you remove<sup>1</sup>. These `.placeholder` files that you see in the various `cron`-related directories are owned by the `cron` package. Of course, the `cron` package does not add any jobs to these directories. Therefore, by themselves, they'd be empty directories. However, other packages can drop files into these directories to activate cron jobs, either directly or by scripting.

What will happen when you purge all the installed packages which add cron jobs? Then `dpkg` will try to remove these now-empty directories to clean up. To prevent this, `cron` adds `.placeholder` files. `sudo` adds a `README` to `/etc/sudoers.d`.

Correspondingly, `dpkg` will not remove non-empty directories. If:

1. a directory was owned by some package, and
2. you added a file manually, or some package added a generated file, to that directory and then,
3. removed the first package,

`dpkg` will warn you that it is not removing that non-empty directory. For example:

```
$ dpkg -S /etc/php5
php5-cli, php5-json: /etc/php5
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge php5-cli
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED
  php5-cli*
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 to remove and 8 not to upgrade.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 479105 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing php5-cli (5.6.11+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1) ...
Purging configuration files for php5-cli (5.6.11+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1) ...
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge php5-json      
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED
  php5-json*
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 to remove and 8 not to upgrade.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 479104 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing php5-json (1.3.7-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1) ...
Purging configuration files for php5-json (1.3.7-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1) ...
WARN: php5-common has been removed, you need to cleanup /etc/php5 yourself.
dpkg: warning: while removing php5-json, directory '/etc/php5/mods-available' not empty so not removed
```

Various PHP modules had programmatically added files to `/etc/php5`, so `dpkg` didn't remove that directory even though what appeared to be last package owning it was being purged.

To contrast, I re-installed `php5-json`, which brought in an updated version, where `php5-common` also now owns `/etc/php5`, where previously it added files programmatically:

```
$ dpkg -S /etc/php5                      
php5-json, php5-common: /etc/php5
$ sudo apt-get purge php5-{readline,common,mysql} 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'php5-mysql' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages will be REMOVED
  php5-common* php5-json* php5-readline*
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 3 to remove and 8 not to upgrade.
After this operation, 1,336 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 479151 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing php5-json (1.3.7-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1) ...
Purging configuration files for php5-json (1.3.7-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1) ...
Removing php5-readline (5.6.11+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1) ...
Purging configuration files for php5-readline (5.6.11+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1) ...
Removing php5-common (5.6.13+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+3) ...
Purging configuration files for php5-common (5.6.13+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+3) ...
$ ls /etc/php5
ls: cannot access /etc/php5: No such file or directory
```

---

<sup>1</sup> For the case of files in `/etc`, this happens when you purge packages.

Comment: Actually I thought `dpkg` would remove empty directories too. But interestingly, there is another non empty file in `/etc/cron.d/`. Since there is already another file, I didn't understand the function of `.placeholder` at there.

Comment: By the way, we see that initially there was no `php5-common`. (Because the first command in the first transcript does not report any `php5-common`) but neverthless, after removing `php5-json`, it is stated that `php5-common` has been removed. Why is that happened?

Comment: @Utku the cron package cannot know whether you or other packages have added files to those directory. Those files are made at package creation time.

Comment: @Utku I think I had removed php5-common long ago, well before I wrote this answer, but not purged, so files belonging to it were still left. dpkg noted this and warned me accordingly. php5-readline added files to `/etc/php5` via scripts, so `dpkg` was never aware of that relation. That's why I removed it, to clear out the directory.

Comment: Then I guess the same situation applied to 2nd transcript as well. (`php5-json` had been removed before but not purged, so it was removed automatically)

Comment: @Utku no, I'd first purged `php5-json`, thereby removing the last installed package owning that directory. Then I reinstalled it, which brought in `php5-common` because of changes in the package.

Comment: But even though you didn't explicitly command to remove `php5-json` in the 2nd transcript, it was removed automatically. That confused me.

Comment: @Utku In the upgraded version, `php5-json` gained a dependency on `php5-common`, which is why it got removed as well.